# Should we lock "Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string" for being too broad?

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

This is the question I'm referring to -- [Read whole ASCII file into C++ std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602013/read-whole-ascii-file-into-c-stdstring)

This question seems to solicit many different opinionated answers and it doesn't have a clear specific problem that one can answer objectively. The way it's asked allows for many different answers, as is the case. I think this question should be locked because even though it is off-topic, it seems to have garnered much attention the past 4 years.

Comment: Are you suggesting *closing/putting oh hold* as too broad, or are you really talking about *locking*?

Comment: @sth At first I thought locking would be appropriate, but then ChrisF pointed the appropriate use for locking. Now I think it should simply be closed/put on hold as too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why lock?

It's only had one answer since November 2013 and that was deleted, so it's not as if it's getting a lot of unwanted attention. Yes, it's got lots of votes, but then again it's an old post so that's almost a given. Clearly it's helpful to a lot of people.

If it's off topic then vote to **close** as such and see if any one else agrees.

It would only be necessary to lock if there were repeated cycle of closing and reopening.

Comment: No, I think the fact that it's asked this way at all is justification for locking it. Your answer is only defending the fact that it hasn't received unwanted attention, but that doesn't mean the question isn't off-topic in the first place.

Comment: @0x499602D2 in that case vote to **close**. A lock is something far more permanent.

Answer (score 6):

Multiple *valid* solutions to a question doesn't make it Too Broad. Surely you know that there are multiple ways of doing just about everything - heck, we have [an entire site](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to finding "creative" solutions to problems.

Too Broad is useful in a few common scenarios:

- **There are multiple questions being asked**. Someone is trying to get a two-fer rather than just posting multiple, separate questions. This is closely related to...
- **Questions that try to cover too much ground**. Asking for help solving a specific problem that arose while writing your OpenGL wireframe renderer is totally legit. Asking for advice on writing said renderer when you've barely more than a list of requirements is too much - a good answer would be a textbook on software design *and* probably include large portions of Foley, van Dam, Feiner and Hughes. These questions often transition gracefully into...
- **Questions that lack any specificity at all**. Now we're in a situation where there are multiple "correct" answers because **there are no criteria for proving anything *incorrect!*** Questions asking for OpenGL tutorials or help designing systems for which no requirements are provided fall into this category, and often become not just too broad but **overly opinion-based**.

So far as I can tell, none of that applies to the question you found though.

Answer (score 1):

The answers ARE a solution to the problem and are not "opinion based answers". Most questions have multiple solutions.That is why there is an 'Add another answer' button in SO.Although some answers may be simpler and easier than the other,they can be used to solve the problem.

But,if you believe it is off-topic, then vote to close it

Else,its better you don't close the question and leave it as it is.

Comment: (fwiw, the OP wouldn't be flagging for closure, he/she would be casting a vote)

Comment: @dennis ,OP will be flagging the question(see 2nd comment of this question)

Comment: No, as in, once you hit 3k rep, if you tried to flag as off-topic, it ends up being a vote-to-close, not a flag.

Comment: I see,edited my answer